# How much is a “glass,” in an old English cocktail recipe (1930)?

Tags: measurements, cocktails, vintage-cooking

Cocktail recipes in a reprint recipe book frequently call for liquors by the measure of a “glass.”  Just how large was this?

Comment: It would *probably* help if you included one or two of the full recipes. It'd make it less of a guess if someone knows the usual percentages in a drink.

Comment: **What** reprint recipe book?

Comment: Taking for example sherry glasses, old (exat age unknown) glasses varied from not much more than a modern shot glass to about twice that.  Modern sherry glasses tend to be larger

Answer (score 8):

I am not sure if "glass" in your recipe is the same as this, but in David Wondrich's book, "IMBIBE!" (about vintage cocktail recipes), he indicates that a "wineglass" measurement in vintage recipes was equal to 2 ounces.